# Javascript Polling in Web2py

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, web2py

I have this code into my main view file:

```
    <html>
            <head>
           <script src="/app/static/js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript">
            <script type="text/javascript">
                jQuery(document).ready(function() {
                    window.setTimeout(function() {
                        var url = '{{=URL('monitor.load')}}';
                        jQuery('#monitor').load(url);
                    }, 10000);
                });
            </script>
            </head>

            <body>
                <div id="monitor"></div>
            </body>
        </html>
```

In order to show into the #monitor div tag the data from monitor.load file:

```
{{=data}}
```

But, its put the data only once after 10 secs, then it doesn't update the data every 10 secs like I want...
if the data is changed in the controller, or is changed in the monitor.load file
nothing happens...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `setInterval()` instead if you want the code to occur multiple times.

**Example:**

```
setInterval("alert('hello!');", 500);
```

This code above will execute the code `alert('hello!');` every 500 milliseconds from when the page is loaded until it is closed.